# How to add sub category (another level) for Woocommerce variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I wanna manage my woocommerce variation in admin panel and single product page I need to add extra field for category of variation
For Example We Have :

Screen
{
    Size,
    Color,
    Resolution,
}

Then I want to add value for size, color and resolution
and in single product page I want tp

Comment: You can add value for size, color, and resolutions from "Configure terms".

Comment: Maybe you can add some custom fields to product variations and use it on a single product page?